# Making HTTP requests faster in Ionic 2/Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, http, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building a soundboard app and it works by making an http request to the server and creating a file that plays the audio. The problem I am having is that when the button is clicked and the audio is played, it takes around 6-7 seconds for the audio to start.

I know it has a lot to do with the user’s internet speed and the server, but I wanted to know if there is anything, I can add to the code to make this process faster

I am using firebase hosting to deliver the audios.

**soundboard.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'soundboard.html'
})
export class SoundboardPage {

  base_url: string = "http://mywebsite.com/sounds";
  sounds: any = [];
  media: any = null;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http.get(this.base_url)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          /* Create a webpage out of the data from the http.get request */
          let content: string = data.text();
          let doc: any = document.createElement("html");
          doc.innerHTML = content;

          /* Extract all "a" tags from it */
          let links: any = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");

          /* Loop through them, saving their title and sound file */
          for(let link of links) {
            let filename = link.getAttribute("href")
            if(filename.startsWith("/")) {
              filename = this.base_url + filename
            }
            else {
              filename = this.base_url + "/" + filename
            }
            this.sounds.push({              
              file: filename
            });
          }
        },
        err => console.error('There was an error: ' + err),
        () => console.log('Get request completed')
       );
  }


  /* Plays a sound, pausing other playing sounds if necessary */
  play(sound) {
    console.log(sound)
    if(this.media) {
      this.media.pause();
    }
    this.media = new Audio(sound.file);
    this.media.load();
    this.media.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should consider including what your template is and what is `content` that you're getting back from the server. Also, if you're using front end frameworks, you should take advantage of what they give you. Rather than creating an html page with what you get back, you should find a way to pass your data to directive(s). There's also an audio plugin that's included in ionic native. That may possibly solve your latency problem as it uses the native APIs (native as in iOS or Android OS level APIs). http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/